# Openstack deployement

Tags: openstack, cluster

I work in a private cloud project with openstack for my internship, my concern is that I have 12 servers in which I must have a controller node, compute node, network node, storage node where I have to install the various services of openstack manually and I do not know how to build each clustered node to deploy services. And can i have the best way to deploy openstack for production ?

Comment: I will suggest following OpenStack guide to understand architecture also
https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/overview.html#example-architecture

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that is a generaly ultra wide question :)  I'd go along with minimal deployment:

https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/openstack-services.html

Such that all-in-one (according to the minimal install) PLUS several controller nodes at each additional machine.